# How can I change Wordpress design for each languages?

Tags: wordpress, wpml

Recently I work on a multilangual website.
When the design was ready I made a translation with WPML.
Then I made some changes on the original version but the translated version doesn't change with it. 
What could be the problem?
Any help would be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

i`m not sure, but this [topic](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/the-same-page-with-different-template-per-language/)
might help you.

> You can uncheck the option "Synchronize page templates" from wpml -> translation management -> multilingual content setup tab.